# Anyone identify this gold piece mixed with some vintage Castle, Pirate, etc sets/minifigs? No LEGO imprint, but all other pieces are LEGO

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

Gold piece next to minifig for size comparison.Interior of part.[[image]][image: []

Comment: There's plenty of space for a LEGO logo on that piece, so my guess is that the absence of such a logo is a major clue, so my guess would be that it isn't LEGO.

Comment: Thanks, Henrik. I was thinking the same thing but the gold matches the king’s crown perfectly. Since it would be the only non-LEGO piece in a box of about 1,000 vintage parts (yes, I verified every part), I just can’t imagine how this one random non-LEGO booger got in there. I’ve tossed several pieces away that I thought weren’t LEGO only to realize they were just unique LEGO parts - Oops! Maybe I’ll hang on to this one a few days. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 6):

I believe the part in question is actually from the Wave 1 "Iron Man: The Animated Series" figure: Hydro Armor with “Deep Sea Weapons”.

[image: Iron Man Action Figure on Blister Package]

(Image from https://www.action-figure-resource.com)

If you look at where the armor is "assembled", the piece in the thigh position (which will go on the forearm), seems to match the piece in question.

I actually have this figure, but can't get to it at the moment.